# Algorithm for finding independent set

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Suppose graph $G$ with $n$ nodes has $2n/3$ independent nodes. How to find at least $½$ of the independent nodes in polynomial time? (No approximation algorithm)

I'm really stuck and not sure where to begin.

Comment: Many authors might treat what you are asking for as finding an [approximation to a maximum independent set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)#Approximation_algorithms).  The greedy algorithm (choosing the vertex of least degree at each step and discarding its neighbors) [has been studied](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02523693) and has a performance ratio that depends on the maximum degree of the graph.